# PHP: Use PHP to read Json's indexes

Tags: php, json

I'm posting this because I want to read Json's indexes without knowing them before, but I can't find any function that could help me.
I really hope someone can help me,
thanks you in advance.

Comment: use `json_decode()` and convert json to php array and use `foreach()`

Comment: I've used json_decode, but I want the program to read the indexes in order to use them after1.

Comment: Include an example of json and what exactly you require.

Comment: 1. Do some research, get some code then clean it and apply to your context. 
2. Run into some bugs, try your best to debug them. 
3. Nothing works you don't know why and you are getting desperate? Post on stackoverflow we will all collaborate to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
<?php

$json_string = '{"foo": "bar", "stack": "overflow"}';
$array = json_decode($json_string, true);
print_r(array_keys($array));
```